# Xcode 6.4 CFBundleIconFiles

Tags: xcode, swift

When I try to submit my app to the app store i get this error: "error itms-90032 invalid image path no image found at the path referenced under key CFBundleIconFiles"

The problem is that I ma not even using CFBundleIconFiles. A search of the entire app shows that it is not present. I just can't figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So where do your icons come from?

Comment: They are in AppIcon in Images.xcassets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They are in AppIcon in Images.xcassets

Okay, but it sounds like you forgot to tell the app target about that. Edit the app target, go to the General tab, and make sure that the target knows where to find the icons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You won't necessarily see `CFBundleIconFiles` in the plist that Xcode created for your project, but `CFBundleIconFiles` does get added to the Info.plist that is submitted to the App Store.

Your bundle icon files are automatically generated from your Asset Catalog icons and added to the bundle.

The details for the icons are contained in `Images.xcassets`.

Check to make sure that the Asset Catalog was not relocated, or the validation will fail, since the icons could not be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I double checked everything you guys posted and everything is good, but still getting the error. I finally just decided to add iconfiles (ios5) to the plist and it worked when I tried to upload. I don't know why that did the trick.